# How to center a TextInput when focus in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a page with 3 `TextInput` components. the problem that I have is when I tap them to insert the actual text, the first two disappear even tho, they're the ones focused. So I want to center the focused `TextInput`.

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.header1}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>New Note</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.headerDesign}>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.header2}>
                </View>
                <View style= {styles.mainPage}>
                    <View style={styles.noteBody}>
                        <TextInput
                         style = {styles.subject} 
                         placeholder='Raport Number/Note Indentifier'
                         onChangeText={(noteTitle)=> this.setState({noteTitle})} 
                         value={this.state.noteTitle}
                         placeholderTextColor='grey'
                         underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>
                         </TextInput>
                         <TextInput
                         style = {styles.calltype} 
                         multiline = {true}
                         numberOfLines = {5}
                         placeholder='Call Type/Other Information'
                         onChangeText={(callType)=> this.setState({callType})} 
                         value={this.state.callType}
                         placeholderTextColor='grey'
                         underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>
                         </TextInput>
                        <TextInput 
                            multiline = {true}
                            numberOfLines = {9}
                            style={styles.textInput}
                            placeholder='Write your note here'
                            onChangeText={(noteText)=> this.setState({noteText})}
                            value={this.state.noteText}
                            placeholderTextColor='grey'
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>
                        </TextInput>
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.addNote.bind(this) } style={styles.addButton}>
                        <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>SAVE</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

            </View>
```

And here is the `StyleSheet`:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
},
mainPage:{
    flex: 2,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
},
header1:{
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 40,
    justifyContent: 'center',
},
title:{
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 20,
},
header2:{
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 40,
    justifyContent: 'center',
},
headerDesign:{
    backgroundColor: '#0000FF',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
},
noteBody:{
    flex: 2,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    zIndex: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 100,
},
textInput: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    textAlignVertical: 'top',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    color: '#000',
    padding: 20,
    borderTopWidth:1,
    borderTopColor: '#000',
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderBottomColor: '#000',
},
addButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 11,
    bottom: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 200,
    backgroundColor: '#0000FF',
    height: 40,
    elevation: 8
},
addButtonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 20,
},
subject:{
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    textAlignVertical: 'top',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 20,
    borderTopWidth:1,
    borderTopColor: '#000',
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderBottomColor: '#000',
},
calltype:{
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    textAlignVertical: 'top',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 20,
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderBottomColor: '#000',
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to make an absolute position for each text input. Use a flex parent with some height and width for each TextInput or if you do want to use absolute position. use all the attributes  `top`, `bottom`, `right`, `left`

Comment: Ok. I updated the code but the first `textinput`'s position is kind of weird. It is placed in the middle of the screen with a 40 width and even if I change the width, it will not help.

Comment: Weird? Screenshot?

Comment: Give he one minute. I was trying something.

Comment: Yes. I forgot to add a `alignSelf: 'stretch',` to the first one.

Comment: Not it works. But when I tap on the last one, the keyboard comes over it and I can't see what am I taping.

Comment: See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html Add it at the root of the component

Comment: If I am doing that, it hides all the `textinput` components.

Comment: Yep..it is only making it worse.